# Android app is incompatible with your device

Tags: android, google-play, publish, tablet

I have published an app in google play but i can't make it compatible with tablets. How can I fix this problem

here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="packageName"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="0.1.3" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<compatible-screens>

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />

    <!--all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <!--all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->        
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

</compatible-screens>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="CompanyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: does your app have any layouts for sw-600 and sw-720 folders?

Comment: yes my have layouts for large and xlarge screen

Comment: nope those layouts might be used by phones. like xperia Z uses xxlarge.

Comment: so i have to change my folders name layout-large to layout-sw600dp and layout-xlarge to layout-720dp

Comment: You need to add a significant amount of information to your question for it to be reasonably answerable. At a minimum, your manifest would be good to post.

Comment: Please check does the tablet has sim support. If it doesnt have sim support it wont be compatible as you have used the permission of CALL_PHONE.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. My Application is not designed as "Multipan" application still I want to make it compatible with 7 inch and 10 inch tablets. I have added "layout-sw600dp" and "layout-sw720dp" folders and removed "layout-large" and "layout-xlarge" folders, and then uploaded it still there is no change.

Answer (score 1):

> layout-sw600dp
>
> layout-sw600dp-land
>
> layout-sw720dp
>
> layout-sw720dp-land

create these folders and paste your layout files to check the problem

edit:
now phones layout varies from small med large xlarge xxlarge. SO create new folders as my answer
 these folders are for devices having min width 600 and 720 which are typical size of tablets

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but Did you add any screenshots for tablets in your app listing??